# Do I need to create a Unit Test Case class for a Struct in Swift?

Tags: swift, unit-testing, xctest, xctestcase

I wonder if there is a need to create a Unit Test Case class or even a separate unit test method to test a Model of it is a Struct?

I trying to follow the TDD to create a Signup feature for my mobile app. On a piece of paper, I have sketched what I need to create:

- ViewController class,
- Presenter class,
- A Validator class to validate Model field values like the email address format and the password length and etc...
- WebService class to send HTTP Request with user details,
- A Signup Form Request Model struct. A Model struct that will be sent over to my server.
- A Signup Response Model struct. A Struct that will be used to convert server response into a Swift struct.

I wonder if there is a need to create a Unit Test Case class or even a separate unit test method to test a Model of it is a Struct? Structs do not have failable initializers. And because Swift struct has a memberwise initializer, there is really nothing to test...

For example. The SignupModel.swift - a separate file:

```
struct SignupModel {
    let firstName: String
    let lastName: String
    let email: String
    let password: String
}
```

Do I really need to create a test method:

```
    func testInit_SignupModelExists() {
       let signupModel = SignupModel(firstName:"John", lastName: "Doe", email: "test@test.com", password: "12345678")


       XCTAssertNotNil(signupModel)
    }
```

Do you guys create this kind of Unit tests when following the TDD?

Comment: Not relevant for TDD perhaps but a struct like this normally gets covered when writing unit test for methods that uses the struct.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson thank you! That's a good idea actually. I will double-check the Code Coverage to see if it covers files that contain a single Struct.

Comment: Great! Swift files that contain a single Struct are not even listed in the code coverage report. I am pretty confident now that in its simplest form there is no need for a test case.

Answer (score 1):

You need to test your functionality with unit tests. In here, there is no any functionality.

If your `init` function may return nil, you may need. But in this case, your initializer never return any value but your create. So we can't say this a functionality.

Comment: That's what I also thought... If I am to create a Unit test for a Model struct then its more like I am testing Apple's Swift language, rather than code I have written.

Comment: @Simplyi That’s correct. Don’t test Apple’s code at all, not even the Cocoa Touch framework. Test only things that _you_ do.

Comment: Thank you, @Matt 